# How to pick a good training set?

Tags: distributions, classification

From what I understand, my training set should represent the underlying distribution of objects, but what if my local view is not such a good representation? For instance I am working on a cell (i.e biological cell) recognition software. So my training set plates of cells. These cells are collected from my region of the world, but different regions offer different distributions of cells and different composition within the cell distribution. How to over come this problem?